# The best practice for communication with database - POST or GET?

Tags: database, post, get

For example, I want to search/insert/get/delete data from database and I'm working with wcf RESTful service.
I have one method for getting data from the table, one method for searching in the table, one method for inserting data in the table and one method for deleting data from the table.

I know that every of these methods can be POST or GET.

But, what is smartest? What is the best practice?

My opinion is that the search and the get method should be GET. The insert and the DELETE method should be POST.

Am I right?

Comment: And you didn't really mean 'communication with database'. You meant 'communication with web server', right?

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev No, I meant communication with database, because my methods are all for working with tables from database.

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev Ok, do you think the title should be 'Communication from web server to web server' ? I thought it should be 'Communication from web server to database'

Comment: Again, do you send HTTP requests to your database?

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev How do you mean?

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev I'm using a database from my client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. The thing about GET is that it should be idempotent as the client (browser) is free to send repeat GETs anytime they want. However the POST can only be sent once (according to the rules).

So anything that changes anything could be a POST. Strictly speaking the delete could be a GET as well, as the resend of the GET will not hurt the delete, but generally it's better if you respect the spirit of the HTTP protocol. See the [HTTP RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) for more details.

Comment: How do you mean the post can be sent only once? I can call my delete method whenever I want, right?

Comment: Sorry to be clear, it's at most once. The browser will never resend the HTTP POST method, it might reset the GET method if it does not get a response or detects a communication failure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the convention.

Use POST for operations that change data or system state. Use GET for queries that don't change anything.

[Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/), for example, enhances this by also using PUT and DELETE, but this is not supported by most webservers  (so there's a workaround for this).

References:

- Nginx does not include support for PUT and DELETE by default: [sorry, only Russian doc is available](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_dav_module.html).
- Same for [Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/324673/enable-http-delete-requests-on-apache-server).
- These two have [70% of the market](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2011/05/02/may-2011-web-server-survey.html).

Comment: Yes, I know that there are more options than POST and GET, but I limited it to those two :)

Comment: "`PUT` and `DELETE` [are] not supported by most webservers" -- *[citation needed]*

Answer (score 1):

[Wiki has a good overview of the HTTP verbs and their use.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)

If I were you, I'd use:

`GET` for search and get operations (since they will not modify data; it's safe to call these operations multiple times)

`POST` for the insert operation

`DELETE` for the delete operation

(IIS has no problem with the `DELETE` verb.)